# Route binding not updating sub component

Tags: vuejs2, vue-component, vue-router

I have a a hard time understanding how components and routes works together. In the documentation, they only talk about one level of components. In case there is multiple level, it does not look like it is working.

I made this http://jsfiddle.net/uvqpracr/7/

and when you click on `init(1)` it initialize the counter with **1** and when you click on `init(5)` it initialize the counter with **5**. In the route component, I declare `v-bind:init-counter="$route.params.initCounter` so when I am in `counter-container`, writing `{{init-counter}}` works, but in the subcomponent `counter`, event if I wrote `v-bind:init-counter="initCounter"` it does not work.

In [this documentation](https://router.vuejs.org/en/essentials/dynamic-matching.html), I can read:

> One thing to note when using routes with params is that when the user navigates from `/user/foo` to `/user/bar`, **the same component instance will be reused**. Since both routes render the same component, this is more efficient than destroying the old instance and then creating a new one. **However, this also means that the lifecycle hooks of the component will not be called**.

I wonder if this is the reason why what I am trying to do does not work. If so I really wonder how I should do it in a simple way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, yes, the components (`counter-container` and its child `counter`) are created just once.

See the log at this [demo **JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/acdcjunior/uvqpracr/16/). No matter how many times you click the links, the `created()`s are only called once each (see the console).

> and when you click on `init(1)` it initialize the counter with **1** and when you click on `init(5)` it initialize the counter with **5**

Not quite. I mean, the clicks don't always initialize the `counter` variable.

Actually, when you click them, the route changes and then `initCounter` (not `counter`, not `total`) changes.

At the **first click**, because the components haven't been created before, then the value of `initCounter` will be used to initialize the `counter` (and `total`).

But in subsequent clicks, even though the `initCounter` **does change even for nested components**, it won't affect the `counter`/`total` variables because they have already been created.

Check the [demo **JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/acdcjunior/uvqpracr/16/). I added the displaying of `counter: {{ counter }} / initCounter: {{ initCounter }}`, so you'll see `initCounter` changes in the `counter` component as well.

## Updating every time

So, you now know that `initCounter` will be used to set `counter`/`total` only once, only when the components are first created.

If you want to update them whenever `initCounter` changes, the solution is to watch the route (using `watch: { '$route' (to, from) { /* react here */ } }`) or, more specifically, watch `initCounter`.

Check [this other demo **JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/acdcjunior/uvqpracr/22/). This one uses `watch` and updates `counter`/`total` whenever `initCounter` is updated.